# Merge 2 SQL insert queries

Tags: sql, merge, insert

Ok not really sure how to explain this but here goes ...

I have a database lets call it foo with 1 table that has 3 rows row1,2,3 (row1 being id int auto) and I have 2 insert sql queries I need to merge so they align:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`row2`) VALUES ('value');

INSERT INTO `table` (`row3`) VALUES ('value');
```

1, Is it possible?
2, If so how?

**Update edit:**

I know its badly written but like I said not really sure how to expain ..:( ok lets try again ...Here is the basic structure as an export..

```
INSERT INTO `bookmarks` (`id`, `name`, `url`) VALUES
(1, '', 'http://twitter.com'),
(2, '', 'http://digg.com'),
(3, '', 'http://stumbleupon.com'),
(4, '', 'http://reddit.com'),

continued further down...this is where I lose the url but gain the name

(830, 'Twitter', ''),
(831, 'Digg', ''),
(832, 'Stumbleupon', ''),
(833, 'Reddit', '');
```

I need to add the name row to the 1st part so it becomes

(4, 'Reddit', 'http://reddit.com'),

[image]

I need to bump the rows/columns up

Comment: Are `row2` and `row3` columns? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Which SQL server software are you using?

Comment: Question is very badly written (i would love to find out how this got a upvote). What do you want to **Merge** with what? Are you trying to `INSERT` to separate rows? Or `UPDATE` existing rows? What columns to the tables have?

Comment: I think it's like.. first 5 rows are ID and URL. another 5 rows are ID and NAME. He's trying to merge those 10 rows so that.. only 5 rows with ID, NAME, URL. But I need to ask. how do we know the link between the URL and NAME. like ID of the NAME-5 is the ID of URL?? may be??

Comment: Let me see if I got this right. You have already got your data in the table, but the data are messed up (`name` is not aligned with `url`), and now you want to fix the data (align everything accordingly)? Or do you just want to know how to insert `url` and `name` simultaneously so you could re-insert all the data again? If it's the latter, then Josh's answer is just about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`row2`,`row3`) VALUES ('val1','val2');
```

Comment: Did you understand the question? Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: It was my understanding that by "merge", he wanted to insert both values under the same auto inc (row1) id. Maybe before he was doing an INSERT, mysql_insert_id(), INSERT W/ ID ?

Comment: So you believe `row2` and `row3` are columns? the OP says he has 3 rows.

Comment: @ The Scrum Meister: He says 3 'rows', but I'm sure he means 3 'columns', as in his example code, the values he aforementioned are in the spots where columns go in the query, minus 'row1', which he mentions is an autoinc. I'm sure he meant `column[1-3]`.

Comment: I agree with you that by 'rows' *she* actually meant columns.